# How to create this MongoMapper custom data type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper, custom-data-type

I'm trying to create a custom MongoMapper data type in RoR 2.3.5 called Translatable:

```
class Translatable < String
  def initialize(translation, culture="en") 
  end 

  def languages
  end

  def has_translation(culture)?
  end

  def self.to_mongo(value) 
  end 

  def self.from_mongo(value) 
  end 
end
```

I want to be able to use it like this:

```
class Page 
  include MongoMapper::Document 
  key :title, Translatable, :required => true 
  key :content, String 
end
```

Then implement like this:

```
p = Page.new 
p.title = "Hello" 
p.title(:fr) = "Bonjour" 
p.title(:es) = "Hola" 
p.content = "Some content here" 
p.save

p = Page.first
p.languages
=> [:en, :fr, :es]
p.has_translation(:fr)
=> true
en = p.title 
=> "Hello" 
en = p.title(:en)
=> "Hello"
fr = p.title(:fr) 
=> "Bonjour" 
es = p.title(:es) 
=> "Hola"
```

In mongoDB I imagine the information would be stored like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4b98cd7803bca46ca6000002"), "title" : { "en" : 
"Hello", "fr" : "Bonjour", "es" : "Hola" }, "content" : "Some content 
here" }
```

So Page.title is a string that defaults to English (:en) when culture 
is not specified.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: David Cuadrado was kind enough to help me part of the way via the MongoMapper Google Group with the following code: http://pastie.org/873220, but I'm not getting the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us how Translatable stores its internal representation of the various translated versions.  Aside from the MongoMapper integration, do you have a working Translatable class?  If so, could you post the full source?

I'll assume, for argument's sake, Translateable has a Hash instance variable called @translated_versions, which maps from culture Symbols to translated Strings.  You could then implement the MongoMapper integration as:

```
class Translatable < String
  attr_reader :translated_versions

  def initialize(value)
    @translated_versions = value
  end

  def self.to_mongo(value)
    value.translated_versions
  end

  def self.from_mongo(value) 
    self.new(value)
  end
end
```

This would get you far enough to store your Translatable instances as MongoMapper keys.  Note that p.languages and p.has_translation(:fr) would still not work, as you only defined those methods on Translatable, not Page.  You'd either need to call p.title.languages and p.title.has_translation(:fr), or add code to Page to delegate those methods to title for you.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use the **i18n gem** to handle + store the translations!
and to just specify a I18N-lookup-key in your model, which then uses the I18N translate() method to lookup the correct translation based on the user's locale..

In your case, I'd suggest to just store a symbolic page title, which is then used as a lookup-key for I18N

The I18N-keys are looked up in the static translation files under `./config/locales/`

See:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Exception:

only if you want have users be able to dynamically specify translations within your web-app, you might want to store the translations in a database.

**After a bit of digging, I found this gem, which stores the translations in ActiveRecord:**

This can probably get adapted for MongoDB pretty easily:

https://github.com/grosser/fast_gettext

https://github.com/grosser/fast_gettext/blob/master/examples/db/migration.rb

Also:

http://groups.google.com/group/rails-i18n/browse_thread/thread/6b7ba3c401890a7e

https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/df498763cd1968c58900d66a322325d9db8b0d06/lib/i18n/backend/active_record/translation.rb#L18

Comment: The exception is the reason for wanting to do this. Thanks for your answer anyway. I do use i18n everywhere else.

Comment: Please check the updated answer - I found the gem which stores the translations in ActiveRecord